# Copy a row with a red highlighted cell from one sheet to another sheet in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I need to see if someone can help me out with my excel code.  I am trying to copy a row that has a cell highlighted red in it to another sheet automatically.  I have 2 sheets, an ST Audits history sheet and a tracking sheet.

I was able to get this code to work for 1 row, but I need it to work for all rows from row 3 down. I also need it to disappear off the tracking sheet once the cell is no longer red, but right now it stays there and the cell just takes the red highlight away. Any help is greatly appreciated.  I tried another forum but nobody seems to know how to fix it (Or they arent replying :( )

CODE:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Cells.Clear
Sheets("ST Audit history").Rows(3).Copy Destination:=Rows(2)
For N = 2 To Sheets("ST Audit history").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Sheets("ST Audit history").Cells(N, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
    Sheets("ST Audit history").Rows(N).Copy Destination:=Rows(UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
  End If
Next N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim shtSrc as worksheet, rw as long
    me.Cells.Clear
    set shtSrc=Sheets("ST Audit history")
    shtSrc.Rows(3).Copy Destination:=me.Rows(2)
    rw=3
    For N = 2 To shtSrc.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If shtSrc.Cells(N, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            shtSrc.Rows(N).Copy Destination:=Me.Rows(rw)
            rw=rw+1
        End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

Comment: That code is still doing the same thing- it only copys the first row and not the others that have red cells, and it is not taking the row out of the tracking sheet.  Any other ideas?  thanks again

Comment: Your question said you wanted to copy the row. As for only the first row being copied, maybe the colorindex is incorrect, or the cells are being colored using conditional formatting?  Add `Debug.Print N, shtSrc.Cells(N, 6).Interior.ColorIndex` just before the `If` line and see what output you get...

Comment: Yes- they are being highlighted with a conditional formatting..I wil ladd that and see what happens.

Comment: If the color is from CF then you won't be able to use colorindex to read that color: you'll have to use the same test which is used in the CF setup.  OR you can try this: http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EPX299/LI041931911.htm  but it's quite a complex thing to do.

Comment: So I can put the formula fro mthe CF in the place of the colorindex code?

Comment: Yes - the same test should do it.

Comment: I keep getting an error- this is my CF code, and I am not sure if I am putting it in the right place?  VB is not my specialty :)  =AND(ISBLANK(H3),G3)

Comment: What's in column G? Is it a true/false value?

Comment: I have a feeling it would be easier for me to auto highlight the rows using a colorindex code instead of conditional formatting- am I right?

Comment: column g is a date- if it is over 36 months from todays date- it highlights it red

Comment: column h is set that if there is a date in it- then it takes the red highlight away

Comment: This is getting too extended to continue here - if you give me your email in a comment we can take this offline. You can delete the email comment once I have it.